# Pyqgis equivalent of OID@ token (in arcpy cursors)

Tags: python, pyqgis

In ArcGIS I often find it very useful to use the `OID@` (object id) token of for example [da.SearchCursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm) when iterating over rows in vector data:

> Additional information can be accessed using tokens (such as OID@) in
>   place of field names

For example if I for some reason would like to select last occurence of duplicate records I would in ArcGIS do (just as an example, made up data etc...):

```
d = {key:val for key,val in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("OIDtest",['sometext','OID@'])} #Dictionary cant have duplicate keys, only last record is kept.
d
{u'A': 1, u'B': 3}
d.values()
[1, 3]
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view="OIDtest", where_clause="{0} IN{1}".format(arcpy.Describe("OIDtest").OIDFieldName, tuple(d.values())))
```

But in QGIS the OID column is hidden(?) and cant be accessed by name. Are there an OID@ equivalent that can be used to select row 2 and 4 when there is nothing else unique to identify the rows by?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found it, `.id()` method and `$id` when used in expression:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

d = {}
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    d[feat['sometext']] = feat.id()

layer.selectByExpression('$id IN{0}'.format(tuple(d.values())))
```